# Program ignoring if statement (MD5 Checker)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, md5

I am fairly new to programming and have just started work experience. I have been asked to produce two applications. One which gets and stores file information such as the file's name, size, last modified time, and MD5 Checksum, and then write a file containing that data for multiple files; this program works fine.

My second program, which I will post code for below, is supposed to check the file created and compare it against the current conditions of the file. If the MD5 sum changes along with other properties, then the program would not give a warning. However, if all properties remain the same but the MD5 changes, then the program would put out a warning, as something went wrong.

The issue I am having is getting the checker program to work as it should. I am a beginner so I would appreciate it if someone would perhaps take a look at my code and see where I've slipped up.

here is the code which I have produced.

```
 files = glob('C:\pytesty\*\*')


filecheck = open('MD5report.dat', 'r')
for fil3 in files:
          fil3md5 = open(fil3, 'rb')
          md5read = fil3md5.read()
          hashy = hashlib.md5(md5read).hexdigest()
          filsize = os.path.getsize(fil3)
          filtime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(fil3))
          fline = filecheck.readline()
          [finame, fiMD5, fiSize, fidate, eofline] = fline.split('|')
          print (hashy + fiMD5)

          if (finame == fil3 and fiSize == filsize and fidate == filtime and fiMD5 != hashy):
                    print(finame + ': Wrong md5')
          else:
                    print(finame + ': is OK')
```

the contents of the 'MD5report' file are as follows:

```
    C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\egwe.bmp|a41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e|0|Mon May  8 19:19:22 2017|
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\ergeagheghergswa.rtf|8274425de767b30b2fff1124ab54abb5|7|Mon May  8 19:19:33 2017|
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\tyi,kmykkymktuk.doc|b3e3d42d4a9454f8b6296f3b822f5259|9216|Mon May  8 19:19:13 2017|
C:\pytesty\pyt01\asdf.txt|e1738d5f7e720f3f3f3745b4e0d07e46|33|Mon May  8 19:00:42 2017|
C:\pytesty\pyt01\ex2.txt|7a9d20dd22c96bea3ea1fa0d01085755|69|Mon May  8 19:01:00 2017|
C:\pytesty\pyt01\exampl3.txt|5d29389c5bb758b0d9d5555825daa095|571|Mon May  8 19:01:25 2017|
```

When I run the program, I get:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e   a41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\egwe.bmp: is OK
8274425de767b30b2fff1124ab54abb5   8274425de767b30b2fff1124ab54abb5
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\ergeagheghergswa.rtf: is OK
b3e3d42d4a9454f8b6296f3b822f5259   b3e3d42d4a9454f8b6296f3b822f5259
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\tyi,kmykkymktuk.doc: is OK
e1738d5f7e720f3f3f3745b4e0d07e46   e1738d5f7e720f3f3f3745b4e0d07e46
C:\pytesty\pyt01\asdf.txt: is OK
7a9d20dd22c96bea3ea1fa0d01085755   7a9d20dd22c96bea3ea1fa0d01085755
C:\pytesty\pyt01\ex2.txt: is OK
5d29389c5bb758b0d9d5555825daa095   5d29389c5bb758b0d9d5555825daa095
C:\pytesty\pyt01\exampl3.txt: is OK
>>>
```

As you can see, the program thinks all the files are 'OK' despite the fact that they are not, as I have deliberately altered the first MD5 checksum in the report file.

I have tried to look for some solutions but they were either unrelated to this particular scenario or simply didn't work.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Edit according to comment:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e   a41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\egwe.bmp   C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\egwe.bmp
0   0
Mon May  8 19:19:22 2017   Mon May  8 19:19:22 2017
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\egwe.bmp: is OK
8274425de767b30b2fff1124ab54abb5   8274425de767b30b2fff1124ab54abb5
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\ergeagheghergswa.rtf   C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\ergeagheghergswa.rtf
7   7
Mon May  8 19:19:33 2017   Mon May  8 19:19:33 2017
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\ergeagheghergswa.rtf: is OK
b3e3d42d4a9454f8b6296f3b822f5259   b3e3d42d4a9454f8b6296f3b822f5259
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\tyi,kmykkymktuk.doc   C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\tyi,kmykkymktuk.doc
9216   9216
Mon May  8 19:19:13 2017   Mon May  8 19:19:13 2017
C:\pytesty\mynewfolder\tyi,kmykkymktuk.doc: is OK
e1738d5f7e720f3f3f3745b4e0d07e46   e1738d5f7e720f3f3f3745b4e0d07e46
C:\pytesty\pyt01\asdf.txt   C:\pytesty\pyt01\asdf.txt
33   33
Mon May  8 19:00:42 2017   Mon May  8 19:00:42 2017
C:\pytesty\pyt01\asdf.txt: is OK
7a9d20dd22c96bea3ea1fa0d01085755   7a9d20dd22c96bea3ea1fa0d01085755
C:\pytesty\pyt01\ex2.txt   C:\pytesty\pyt01\ex2.txt
69   69
Mon May  8 19:01:00 2017   Mon May  8 19:01:00 2017
C:\pytesty\pyt01\ex2.txt: is OK
5d29389c5bb758b0d9d5555825daa095   5d29389c5bb758b0d9d5555825daa095
C:\pytesty\pyt01\exampl3.txt   C:\pytesty\pyt01\exampl3.txt
571   571
Mon May  8 19:01:25 2017   Mon May  8 19:01:25 2017
C:\pytesty\pyt01\exampl3.txt: is OK
```

Comment: One of your other conditions must be failing in addition to the hashes not matching. Have you tried printing the values for the other data (filename, date, etc.) to make sure they match like you expect?

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. For example, print out the results of the individual comparisons, so you can see exactly why the unexpected code path is being taken.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only prints that the hashes don't match if all the other conditions are met. Therefore, if for some reason your filenames, dates, or sizes aren't the same, if will never execute the code that says the hash is wrong. It will instead go directly to the line that says the file is okay.

I suggest checking each of these conditions separately in order to make sure the correct error message is being shown.